# Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'ServiceBusSettings.ConnectionString' is missing or empty

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

The Main Method is as shown below,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddServiceBus(sbOptions =>
            {
                sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
                sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 16;
            });
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });

        var host = builder.Build();

        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

And the *local.settings.json* file is like,

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusSettings.ConnectionString": "Endpoint=***",
    "SQLConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
}
```

And am Consuming **ServiceBusTrigger** as shown below,

```
public static class RegisterSK
{
    [FunctionName("RegisterSK")]
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "S2", Connection = "ServiceBusSettings.ConnectionString")]string topicItem, ILogger log)
    {
        //logger.LogInformation(message);
    }
}
```

While running the program am getting error like,

**Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'ServiceBusSettings.ConnectionString' is missing or empty.**

Am new to Azure WebJobs. Not getting what wrong am doing. Refereed previous solutions but didn't got any proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AppSettings.json and keep the connection string as

```
"AzureWebJobs": { "extensions": { "ServiceBus": { "ConnectionStrings": { "Primary": "[your connection string here]" } } } }
```

Comment: What I need to mention in place of Connection=" " ? Empty String?

Comment: your service bus connection string

Comment: Then why we need to mention the same ConnectionString in AppSettings.json ? Sorry am new to Azure WebJobs...

Comment: that is what i am refering to. you need to refer, because deployed app takes it from appsettings.json

Comment: I think i asked wrong in my previous comment. I meant to ask is what I need to give in Connection = " " which is there in the method public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "S2", Connection = "ServiceBusSettings.ConnectionString")]string topicItem, ILogger log)

Comment: And do i need to register appsettings.json somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/sajeetharan/dotnetcore-webjob/tree/master/NetCoreWebJob refer this